# Getting PageRequestManagerServerErrorException on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm getting the following error:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.
```

After I click on an the following button:

```
<input type="submit" class="buttonFormPrimary" id="ctl00_contentBlockPlaceHolder_lvQuals_ctrl7_btnClose" onclick="showhide(qComment_353);" value="Close" name="ctl00$contentBlockPlaceHolder$lvQuals$ctrl7$btnClose">
```

Which is being created the following control:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClose" Text="Close" CssClass="buttonFormPrimary" OnClientClick='<%#Eval("Qual_ID","showhide(qComment_{0})") %>' />
```

As I didn't develop the application, I'm not quite sure how to debug the error.

Comment: Are controls being dynamically added to the page which will then not match the contents of ViewState?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. I updated the code for the control which creates the button above.

Comment: Is there any client side code that adds, removes or changes controls on the page? What does the showhide Javascript function look like. Did this behavior just start? If so, what was changed from when it was working?